# Can't space listBox and buttons using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, layout, grid-layout

I've created a new frame that will hold:
-A label
-A listbox
-A button
The frame is part of the main window.
When I run the application, the label, listbox & button are close to each other and I can't space them
This is the partial code of the concerned parts:

```
from tkinter import *
drsBlue='#004A99'


class GUI:

    def __init__(self,):
        w = 520
        h = 350
        self.window = Tk()
        for i in range(0,3):
            self.window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        ws = self.window.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.window.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2) -(w/2)
        y = (hs/2) -(h/2)
        self.window.title("Invoice handling application")
        self.window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.window.configure(bg=drsBlue)
        self.homeDirectory = r'C:/Users/Shtlrs/Desktop/Clients folder/'
        self.window.resizable(False,False)

        self.listBoxFrame = Frame(self.window, bg=drsBlue)
        self.listBoxFrame.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.clientNamesLabel = Label(self.listBoxFrame,text="Please select a client from\n the following list")
        self.clientNamesLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # clients listbox
        self.clientsListBox = Listbox(self.listBoxFrame)
        self.clientsListBox.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # ----List Box Frame----#
        self.backFromListBoxBtn = Button(self.listBoxFrame, text="Back", bg='#1b98e0', fg="white", width=20, height=2)
        for i in range(0,4):
            self.listBoxFrame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.listBoxFrame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.backFromListBoxBtn.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s=Gui()
```

And what I get is the following picture:
[image]

What am I missing to space them apart ?

Comment: The `grid` method has attributes for adjusting padding. Have you tried using them?

Comment: Oe, I did. But I had completely forgotten about them... It works just fine now, thanks a lot for reminding me.